# visual representation of gradle dependency

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

i have used the `gradle dependencies` to analyse the project dependencies.

Does gradle support a visual representation of the dependency graph instead of the current format  ( The current format serves very well , but a visual representation would be more easier to read and interpret )

i tried htmlDependencyReport using the below plugin

```
apply plugin: 'project-report'
```

But I could not get a visual representation of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and found this gradle plugin: https://github.com/nevers/gradle-dependency-grapher
But I couldn't try it out yet, and don't know if it is working with any current gradle version.

The script seems pretty simple: It just creates a grahviz configuration in the .dot format and feeds it directly to graphiz (seems this must be installed on the system).

If I find some time, I will give it a try.
It should be possible to modify the script to just create a *.dot file in the build folder. I could then feed it to http://www.webgraphviz.com/.